# evidence silokas: transmigration even among animals and plants and insects or devatas

Tags: scripture, vedas, gods

I need the evidence shlokas that explain that soul's transmigration even among animals and plants and insects or devatas for convincing those who do not believe soul's transmigration among them.

Comment: Bhagavad Gita 16.20. Also Chandogya Upanishad 5.10.7-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hare Krishna

Mahabharata, Shanti Parva, Moksha Dharma parva, chapter 302

तम:सत्वरजोयुक्तस्तासु तास्विह योनिषु | नियते प्रतिबुद्धित्वातबुद्धजनसेवनात|| 43

Due to the association with material nature the Jiva gets endowed with the qualities of goodness, passion and ignorance.Due to the association with those persons who identify with bodily concept of life, the Jiva further takes birth in the species which are in modes of goodness,  passion and ignorance.

सहवासविनाशित्वान्नान्यो अहमिति मन्यते| यो अहम् सो अहम् इति हि युक्तत्वा गुणानेवानुवर्तते ||44

Due to the constant association with material nature, the rememberance of one's constitutional position is forgotten, thus the purusha thinks that he is not different from the body. " I am that", "I am this", "I am the son of such and such person" , "I am of such and such caste", thinking so, the Jiva follows the traits of Sattva, rajas and tamo gunas.

तामसा निरयम यान्ति राजसा मनुशानथ | सात्विका देवलोकाय गच्छन्ति सुखभागिनी ||47

By the mode of ignorance, the soul endowed with that particular body falls into the depths of hell, the soul endowed with the mode of passion goes to the world of humans, and those souls who are participants in the mode of goodness reaches the planets of the demigods.

निष्कैवल्येन पापेन तिर्यग्योनिमवाप्नुयात | पुण्यपापेन मानुष्यम पुन्येनैकेन देवता : ||48

Due to excessive sinful activities, the soul takes birth in animal, bird, beast species. By the resultant action of mixture of sinful and pious activities the soul takes birth among human species.Therefore by solely being pious does the jiva takes birth in Demigod species.

एवं अव्यक्तविषयम क्षरमाहुर्मनीषिण: | पंचविंशतिमो yo अयं ज्ञानदेव प्रवर्तते || 49

That which is a product of the association of prakrti and purusha is called as the fallible -kshara by learnt sages and the Parama Purusha is the akshara the infallible.

Chapter 303

एवंप्रतिबुद्धत्वातबुद्धमनुवर्तते | देहाद देहसहस्त्राणि तथा समभिपद्यते || 1

O King this way the Jiva being ignorant of his constitutional position, follows the path of ignorance, that is why the spirit soul keeps on transmigrating from one species to thousands of other species

तिर्यग्योनिसहस्त्रेषु कदाचिद देवतास्वपि | उपपद्यति संयोगात गुनै: सह गुणक्षयात || 2

Due to association with the modes of material nature, the Jiva by being endowed with its quality sometimes takes birth in animal species, and sometimes in Demigod species.

मानुषत्वाद दिवं याति दिवो मानुष्यमेव च | मानुष्यान्निरयस्थानमानन्तयम प्रतिपद्यते || 3

Sometimes in human form he attains the merit to go to the heavenly planets, sometimes he returns back to the earthly planet and sometimes from earthly planet he goes to hellish planets.

कोशकारो यथा आत्मानम् कीट: समवारुन्धति | सूत्रतन्तुगुणैर्नित्यं तथायमगुणो गुणै: || 4

Just as the silk worm binds itself as a cocoon in all direction due to its own web, in the same way the Jiva atma who is not a product of material quality binds himself due to the result of his material deeds.

तिर्यग्योनिसहत्रेषु कदाचिद देवतास्वपि | अभिमन्यत्यभीमानात तथैव सुकृतान्यपि || 8

Sometimes he identifies himself as an animal in the animal species, sometimes he assumes the identity of a Demigod, thus due to the result of identification with particular species the jiva experiences the result of his particular actions performed in those particular bodies.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Severus Snape, this is what I really want to get. These evidence silokas will help people to understand truth. I really appreciate. Thank you so much (^o^)